# MySQL - Finding out the table name in a column in the search results

Tags: mysql, database

Hi i'm using a union to search to tables in a database, this works great.

I've been trying to receive the name of the table in a column so i can use that data but i haven't managed, below is the MySQL code showing my union.

```
(
   SELECT productname, id, filename 
   FROM mobiles
   WHERE productname LIKE  '%app%'
)
UNION 
(
   SELECT productname, id, filename
   FROM tablets
   WHERE productname LIKE  '%app%'
)
```

Below is the results table and i've added the "tables" column to show from which table the record came from.

```
*************************************
productname * id * filename * table
*************************************
Iphone 4s   * 1  * bla.png  * moblies
Tablet      * 23 * hi.png   * tablets
Tablet Mini * 25 * fi.jpg   * tablets
iphone 5    * 10 * bl.png   * mobiles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the tables column in your query:

```
(
   SELECT productname, id, filename, 'mobiles' as tablename
   FROM mobiles
   WHERE productname LIKE  '%app%'
)
UNION ALL
(
   SELECT productname, id, filename, 'tablets' as tablename
   FROM tablets
   WHERE productname LIKE  '%app%'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(
   SELECT productname, id, filename, 'moblies' `table`
   FROM mobiles
   WHERE productname LIKE  '%app%'
)
UNION
(
   SELECT productname, id, filename, 'tablets'
   FROM tablets
   WHERE productname LIKE  '%app%'
)
```